# Why was there a need to go from Objective-c to Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I want a specific and clear answer to my question. Why are iOS programmers migrating Objective-C projects to Swift language?

Comment: this comment gave me a slight relief!!! I was in a dilemma either to master objective -c or spread wings to swift!!! So far, I wanted to stick with objective -c and master it and then go to swift!!! @rmaddy

Answer (score 2):

IMO There was no need to go from Objective-C to Swift. I suspect a lot of migration is because it is "New and Shiny" and a feeling that it is the way Apple is moving.

Comment: Apple is moving to Swift. It's not a feeling.

Comment: That is an answer to a different question, the question is: "Why was there a need to go from Objective-C to Swift?". There is as yet no reason to move and Swift is still changing. Somewhere in the future it may be necessary. Swift still needs more functionality but it getting better. It is also a very large and complicated language.

Comment: It is a comment, not an answer. I'm not moving yet. I prever Objective-C, I don't want to migrate my projects, Swift is work in progress and the same language as the frameworks works best.

Comment: @Willeke I completely agree.